# Isn't C# finalizer mechanics fundamentally flawed even for the case it was designed for?

Tags: c#

My understanding is that the main reason why finalizers in C# exist is to provide a "safety net" in case you have a class with unmanaged resources and you forget to dispose it.

Let's look at this little C# method:

```
public int GetValue()
{
    var calculator = new Calculator();
    return calculator.GetValue();
}
```

The `Calculator` class is a C++/CLI class which contains unmanaged resources and it should be clearly disposed, ideally with help of using statement. But hey, I forgot to do that!

The `Calculator` class looks like this:

```
// header Calculator.h
public ref class Calculator
{
    public:
        Calculator();
        ~Calculator();
        int GetValue();
    protected:
        !Calculator();
    private:
        CalculatorNative* _calculatorNative;
};

// implementation Calculator.cpp
Calculator::Calculator()
{
    _calculatorNative = new CalculatorNative();
}

int Calculator::GetValue()
{
    return _calculatorNative->GetValue();
}

Calculator::~Calculator()
{
    this->!Calculator();
}

Calculator::!Calculator()
{
    delete _calculatorNative;
    _calculatorNative = nullptr;
}
```

The `CalculatorNative` class is a standard C++ class which does some time-consuming calculation in its `GetValue` method (I think details are not important here).

Now, the `calculator` object for which I forgot to call Dispose, becomes eligible for garbage collection right after the `CalculatorNative::GetValue()` gets called in `Calculator::GetValue()`.

So imagine that the `CalculatorNative::GetValue()` method is in the middle of its heavy calculation and now GC starts to sniff around and finds out that `calculator` can be collected (its `this` is never used again). But it has a finalizer, so it adds the finalizer to finalizers queue. The `CalculatorNative::GetValue()` method is still calculating something and now the `Calculator::!Calculator()` (the finalizer) runs on a different thread and, oh my god, it deletes `_calculatorNative` even though it is still doing something! And of course, `CalculatorNative::GetValue()` method crashes badly.

Now the questions:

- Is this really the way finalizers are meant to be used?
- Is it possible to write correct finalizer for even such a simple scenario I have just described?

EDIT:
Now I see that the title might sound little bit offending.
I'm sorry for that. It's definitely not my intention.
I just have spent too much time debugging that problem :-(

Comment: "finalizers in C# exist is to provide a "safety net" in case you have a class with unmanaged resources and you forget to dispose it" - no, **never**. In fact, it's possible that GC will *not run at all* and no finalizer will be executed.

Comment: How can it be in the middle of anything if there’s no reference to the object anymore? How has it returned from the call without finishing what it wants to do? If it does and spawns a thread to do something then that’s a design issue

Comment: This is a difficult topic to get to grips with but the correct way to handle this would be to make sure GC cannot happen in the middle of  a call to the native code. For instance, you could fix this by doing `int result = _calculatorNative.GetValue(); GC.KeepAlive(this); return result;` (I'm not sure what language you're writing your class in since you're using `->` and `::` so you will have to adapt to your language)

Comment: Basically, you're deferencing `this` to get `_calculatorNative`, and then you call the `GetValue()` method, but if this was the *last* reference to the object referred to by `this`, it is now eligible for collection as per optimization rules. You need to ensure your `this` object is kept alive until your native code returns.

Comment: So yes, it is working as it should, but there are a lot of pitfalls, as you've discovered.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen As per optimization rules, a variable in a method that is no longer used is considered dead and not counted towards roots to objects, and thus not part of the references that keeps said object alive. This even includes `this`, so if there are actually no more references to the object on which you're calling a method, it is in fact eligible for collection even if there is a method still in-flight. This is not a problem, *normally*, unless you used `this` to get a pointer to unmanaged memory that the finalizer tears down. OP is right to question it, but it is working as intended.

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko Yes, finalizers might not run at all. But they can still be understood as a "safety net" for the case you forget to call Dispose. Credit for "safety net" wording goes to Raymond Chen and his article [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure your object is not eligible for collection while you're calling native code.

One way to do this would be to rewrite `GetValue` as such:

```
public int GetValue()
{
    int result = _calculatorNative.GetValue();
    GC.KeepAlive(this);
    return result;
}
```

This ensures there is no way GC can tear down your object and make it freachable until after the call to your native object has returned, even if there are no more live references to the object.

---

Since the comments on the question seems to indicate there must be more going on than your example code, I will here break down what the problem is.

In your first method:

```
public int GetValue()
{
    var calculator = new Calculator();
    return calculator.GetValue();
}
```

There is no more use for the `calculator` variable after the call instruction, which means that once the execution has transitioned into `GetValue`, `calculator` is considered dead and no longer used to hold the `Calculator` object alive.

However, we just passed that reference to the `GetValue` method as the `this` implicit parameter, so let's look at that method (which I'm rewriting to be C# syntax just because):

```
int GetValue()
{
    return _calculatorNative.GetValue();
}
```

You can squint and look at this method as though it was written like this:

```
int GetValue()
{
    var localVariable = this._calculatorNative;
    return localVariable.GetValue();
}
```

After you have dereferenced `this` to get to `_calculatorNative`, `GetValue` no longer has a use for `this`, and it means that unless there are other references holding the object alive, *there are no more references to the object*.

Since we were called from the only other method that had a reference to the object, and this object also no longer has a live reference to it, for all intents and purposes this object is now eligible for collection, **even if we're still in the middle of a call to the native GetValue() method**.

So if GC happens, and the finalizer is called, this *will* cause a problem as the method we're still executing is on a object in a memory block we now delete (as per the code in the finalizer).

The solution is "simple", in the sense that you can easily add some code to this example to make sure this problem goes away, but as OP is writing in his comment below this answer, for more complex situations it might get out of hand really quickly. Nevertheless, this is *by design* and you need to both be aware of it and design accordingly.

The fix is, as shown above, to ensure that the object is not eligible for collection until after the call to the native method has completed, and this can be done with the opaque `GC.KeepAlive(this)` method call. This is a no-op method call but it has been flagged in such a way that the compiler cannot optimize it out, and thus there *is* a use for the `this` variable after the native call and thus the object is *not* eligible for collection.

However, it is eligible for collection before the method returns, after the call to `GC.KeepAlive` has completed but before we returned. As with most other situations, this should no longer be a problem.